# How to format <td> value in angular dynamic table

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

am trying to format displayed value in an angular table

this is my table right now

[image]

instead of showing the link am trying to format the displayed content link

instead of  https://www.udemy.com/course/amazon-alexa-101-publishing-alexa-skills-without-coding/

am trying to show  [**amazon alexa 101 publishing alexa skills without coding**]

i have tried in nodejs

```
var url = require('url');
var adr ='https://www.udemy.com/course/technology-strategy-success/?couponCode=05DIwC2320';
var q = url.parse(adr, true);
var data = q.pathname.replace("/course/", '');
var output = data.replace("/", '');
console.log(output);
```

this is my ts file

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from '../../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.css']
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit{


  udemydata = [];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.apiService.getCoupen().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        this.udemydata = data;
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('err', error);
      }
    );


  }

}
```

this is my component.html file

```
 <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table align-items-center table-flush">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">S.No</th>
                <th scope="col">course</th>
                <th scope="col">Link</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let data of udemydata; let i = index;">
                <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                <td>{{data["courseidhref"]}}</td>
                <td><a href ="{{data['courseidhref']}}" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-icon btn-3 btn-primary" type="button">
                  <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="ni ni-send"></i></span>
                  <span class="btn-inner--text">Enroll Now</span>
                </button></a></td>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that Angular runs in user's browser, so you want to use the `URL` class, instead of Node's `url` module, as that is only available in Node runtime.

The, we can break down the process into a few steps:

```js
const url = 'https://www.udemy.com/course/technology-strategy-success/?couponCode=05DIwC2320';
// first, convert to URL class so that it can do the parsing for us.
const parsedUrl = new URL(url);
// we want to ignore the host and query string, so we only need the pathname, as you have yourself discovered.
const pathName = parsedUrl.pathname;
// then, let's split the pathname on any "/" characters.
const urlParts = pathName.split('/');
// this produces some empty strings, so let's get rid of them
const nonEmptyParts = urlParts.filter(x => x !== '');
// now we are left with proper url parts.
// In our case: [ "course", "technology-strategy-success" ]

// Assuming that the last element is always the course name:
const coursePart = nonEmptyParts.pop(); // or, nonEmptyParts[nonEmptyParts.length - 1]

// Finally, let's get rid of the hyphens, replacing them with spaces.
// The regex has two parts:
// 1. /-/ stands for match hyphens
// 2. g stands for "global" - we want to replace ALL hyphens, not just the first one
const courseName = coursePart.replace(/-/g, ' ');
```

If you want to add a bit more sugar, you could also change the first letter of the course title to be a capital.

```js
const title = courseName[0].toUpperCase() + courseName.slice(1);
// Technology strategy success
```

If you want to capitalize every word:

```js
const title = courseName.split(' ')
              .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
              .join(' ');
// Technology Strategy Success
```

Now, to show it in Angular you could go about it in a few ways:

1. After you receive the data from your service, convert it so that the data also has the course title.
2. Create a method in your component that converts url to course title and call it in the template: `<td>{{convertHrefToTitle(data.courseidhref)}}</td>`
3. Create a `courseTitle` Pipe that transforms hrefs to titles. You would use it like so:
   `<td>{{data.courseidhref | courseTitle}}</td>`

Option 1 is fairly simple. When we get the data, we transform it once.

Option 2 is very simple too, but the function will run VERY frequently, on every change detection cycle. This might affect performance if used without thinking.

Option 3 is slightly more complicated, but it will NOT run on change detection cycle unless the href itself has changed. [Read more about pipes ion official docs.](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Here's an example of how to use Option 1:

Given interfaces

```js
interface OriginalData {
  courseidhref: string;
}

interface TransformedData {
  courseidhref: string;
  title: string;
}
```

```js
transformData(data: OriginalData ): TransformedData  {
  return {...data, title: this.hrefToTitle(data.courseidhref)}
}

hrefToTitle(href: string): string {
  // paste the solution from above into here
}

ngOnInit() {

    this.apiService.getCoupen().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        const transformedData = data.map(course => this.transformData(course));
        this.udemydata = transformedData;
        console.log(data, transformedData);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('err', error);
      }
    );

  }
```

Finally, in your template you can do

```html
<td>{{data.title}}</td>
<td><a href ="{{data.courseidhref}}" target="_blank">...
```

Comment: transformData(data: OriginalData ): TransformedData  {
  return {...data, title: this.hrefToTitle(data.courseidhref)}
}

hrefToTitle(href: string): string {
  // paste the solution from above into here
}


i don't understand these two functions please explain  I have created two interface file and how to pass value here

Comment: @DHAYALV the transformData function is called in the ngOnInit hook in my example.